# Delete the last Char of a PHP String

Tags: php

My Problem : i cant delete the last char of a string :

```
  foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $item)
{
    $string .= $item.', ';
}

$markte=rtrim($string ,", ");
```

Comment: This should work fine. Can you post the exact code and the value of the variable before and after?

Comment: Please post input data and what expected outcome you want. It seems that your code will  work. BTW you can go for `implode()` for a better solution

Comment: you have to first declare `$string` variable as empty . i execute this code and found its working .

Comment: [**+266k more dupes here**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+trim+last+char+of+string+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Oh ye it worked ;)

Answer (score 1):

Better use php `implode` function:

```
$string = implode(', ', $_POST['checkbox']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php